# Calculating temporal monthly lag between 2 datasets in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, time-series

I want to calculate how many months pass before the terrestrial water storage reacts and peaks in reaction to precipitation using an raster, time-series Image Collection with 2 bands namely 'precipitation' and 'lwe_thickness_csr' in GEE - how would one go about this?

What I have been trying with no success:

```
// region of interest
var roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([26, -24, 29, -27]);
Map.centerObject(ee.Geometry.Point (28.0328, -26.1372), 9);

// Import terrestrial water storage change dataset
var collection_GRACE = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GRACE/MASS_GRIDS/LAND')
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .filter(ee.Filter.date('2002-01-01', '2016-12-31')) 
    .map(function(image){return image.clip(roi)})
    .select('lwe_thickness_csr');

// Import precipitation CHIRPS dataset
//Function for monthly sum over a period
var monthly_sum_CHIRPS = ee.List.sequence(0, 1*179).map(function(n){
var start3 = ee.Date('2002-01-01').advance(n,'month');
var end3 = start3.advance(1,'month');
return ee.ImageCollection('UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY')
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .filterDate(start3,end3)
  .map(function(image){return image.clip(roi)})
  .sum()
  .select('precipitation')
  .set('system:time_start',start3.millis());
});
var collection_CHIRPS = ee.ImageCollection(monthly_sum_CHIRPS)
    .select('precipitation');

// Combine datasets
var joinB = collection_GRACE.select('lwe_thickness_csr');
var joinA = collection_CHIRPS.select('precipitation');
var filter2 = ee.Filter.equals({
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
});
var simpleJoinB = ee.Join.inner();
var innerJoinB = ee.ImageCollection(simpleJoinB.apply(joinA, joinB, filter2));
var joinedB = innerJoinB.map(function(feature) {
  return ee.Image.cat(feature.get('primary'),feature.get('secondary'));
});

Map.addLayer(joinedB,{},'TWS_CHIRPS');

// Calculate the time-lag between the independent variable (CHIRPS) and the response from the dependent variable TWS (GRACE)
// Based on time-series excel plots I can see a lag of roughly 8 months
// Moving the GRACE data on by 8 months, results in a mimicry of the pattern although this will be longer and shorted in different areas - hence why I want to calculate the correlations
var lagMonths = 8;
var MONTH = 1;
var year = 2010;
var lag = function(leftCollection, rightCollection, lagMonths) {
 var filter = ee.Filter.and(
 ee.Filter.maxDifference({
 difference: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * lagMonths, // this only counts up to days and don't know how to make it months
 leftField: 'system:time_start',
 rightField: 'system:time_start'
 }),
 ee.Filter.greaterThan({
 leftField: 'system:time_start',
 rightField: 'system:time_start'
 }));

 return ee.Join.saveAll({
 matchesKey: 'images',
 measureKey: 'delta_t',
 ordering: 'system:time_start',
 ascending: false, // Sort reverse chronologically
 }).apply({
 primary: leftCollection,
 secondary: rightCollection,
 condition: filter
 });
};

// Apply the lagged function 
// Advanced cross-correlation----------------------------------------------------
// Join the chirps and TWS data with the lagged time
var lag_CHIRPStws = lag(joinB, joinA, lagMonths);


var merge = function(image) {
  var merger = function(current, previous) {
    return ee.Image(previous).addBands(current);
  };
  return ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
image.get('images')).iterate(merger, image);
};
var merged8 = ee.ImageCollection(lag_CHIRPStws.map(merge));

// Compute covariance over time. This will return a 2x2 array image. 
// Pixels contains variance-covariance matrices.
var covariance = function(mergedCollection, band, lagBand) {
return mergedCollection.select([band, lagBand]).map(function(image) {
return image.toArray();
}).reduce(ee.Reducer.covariance(), 8);
};
Map.addLayer(covariance,{},'covariance_CHIRPSgws');
```

Comment: Script is incomplete so, it is not adequate to be ran. Additionally, covariance is a function; not an object to be added as a layer.